# HotSpot JIT, dead code elimination and side effects?

Tags: jvm, jvm-hotspot

HotSpot can perform JIT optimisations to remove dead code, making the code faster and smaller.

How does it know that the code it is removing doesn't have side-effects, or if it calls into native code; say, through a HotSpot intrinsic such as `System.nanoTime()`? Does it avoid calling methods and rely on in-lining to know whether an expression has side-effects, or does it only work for eliminating `if` cases?

Comment: It can only remove code it knows is not called or results which are not used. If it doesn't know what a method does, it can't remove it. e.g. if you call System.nanoTime() but don't use it's result, it still can't eliminate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many hotspot optimizations happen after inlining, so they only require local knowledge. DCE applies to branches and  unused results.

Dead branches are easy to prune because they cannot have side-effects when they're not reachable.

Unused results can back-popagate their deadness until they either leave the local (after inlining!) scope or hit something that has side-effects, which is no different from a used result.

Intrinsics are not native code in the same sense as JNI. The methods are declared native, but the point of an intrinsic is that the [compiler has more knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function) about how to optimize it than arbitrary native code.